# How to make ports in a docker container running Windows host available to a local network

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker 19.3.2 on a Windows 10 host and would like to make 2 ports in my container available to everyone in my local network.
I'm able to access the ports locally but cannot seem to understand how to make them available to the network.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  buildbot:
    image: buildbot/buildbot-master:master
    ports:
      - "8010:8010"
      - "9989:9989"
```

Comment: open windows firewall for the ports, and your team will access it using your_ip:port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you map the ports on your docker-compose.yaml file they are already available on your local IP address also on your local network address, as mentioned in a comment you only need to go to the windows defender and open the firewall to add a rule and allow the inbound traffic for that ports or allow the inbound traffic for the docker application.

My recommendation is to allow the inbound traffic for all the docker application to avoid problems of having more than one services running on different ports and you will need to review the firewall every time you run new services with a different port number.